# Blast Two sequences from a python script

Tags: alignment, bioinformatics, biopython

I have a list of pairs of proteins and I want to compare speed and accuracy of "BLAST Two Sequences" to a Smith-Waterman program for alignment. 
I know there is a "Blast Two Sequences" option on NCBI website, but I would like to run it from a python script. Perhaps Biopython has this capability? 
If I cannot use Blast Two Sequences, I will compare different versions of Smith-Waterman, but this would not be nearly as exciting :) 
OR, if anyone has another idea for a great senior year project in Bioinformatics involving comparing pairs of proteins, please don't hesitate to let me know！ Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[Chapter 7 (BLAST)](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#htoc81) of the Biopython Tutorial and Cookbook should have what you're looking for.

The `NCBBI` module allows interaction with online BLAST tools, `Bio.Blast.Applications` has a number of different local alignments utilities, and the `Bio.Seq` module contains objects to interact with different sequences.

Biopython's [documentation](http://biopython.org/wiki/Documentation) is quite good and the [API](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/) is generally well-written. If you're looking for an interesting project, I suggest you read the [Tutorial and Cookbook](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial)- it's a good overview of what Biopython has to offer.